# Suppose that we have 3 red balls, 6 blue balls, and 7 green balls. Determine the number of ways to put 8 balls into one box

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I can tackle this problem by first listing out the # of red balls: 0,1,2,3. But this seems brute force to me and I don't know what to do if the number and the variety goes up, Can someone give me a hint on a more intuitive approach?((balls with the same color are considered identical))

Comment: There are two very different answers, depending on whether balls of the same colour are considered identical, or distinct.

Comment: they are considered identical and i think this is more difficult

Comment: An analysis like the one you began will work reasonably quickly.

Comment: But what if the number of variety goes up, that will become nearly impossible for such a straightforward counting

Comment: Indeed it will. If we had lots of balls of each type, $8$ or more, then please see Stars and Bars, Wikipedia. However, Stars and Bars needs substantial adjustment if there are restrictions, and things get messy. One can use generating functions, but that ultimately does not help much for getting explicit counts in complex situations.

Comment: But how to apply stars and bars?

Comment: Stars and Bars will work most nicely if we have $\ge 8$ of each colour.  Adjustments for when there are real limits on the number available in each colour are quite painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to use stars and bars here is to imagine that the balls are identical, and that there are $3$ magical boxes that change the color of the ball put in to red, blue or green.

We also note that at most one box can violate the constraints, which simplifies working greatly.

Using stars and bars, and excluding forbidden combos by pre-placing $4,7$ and $8$ balls respectively in the red, blue and green box,

number of ways $= \dbinom{10}2 - \dbinom62 - \dbinom32 - \dbinom22 = 26$

Comment: Thanks, I got it! But what if the constraints are even harsher say only 2 red balls, then you might have 2 boxes violating the rules right?

Comment: With  max 2 red balls also, you'd have only 1 box violating the rule at a time, but yes, in general, you will carefully have to apply inclusion-exclusion

Comment: about the violation of red boxes, do I need to take into account that may be there are 5,6,7and8 or can I just leave Rhodes cases to the other 2boxes?

Comment: I don't understand "Rhodes cases". After putting 4 in red box, there are 4 left to put *without restriction* to all three boxes.

Comment: But chances are that a red box may contain 5, 6, 7 or even 8 balls, right? Or is that case taken care of by the other two boxes?

Comment: Since we have pre-placed 4 balls in the red box, it may contain 4/5/6/7/8 balls.  **All** such cases need to get excluded and are automatically excluded as impermissible by  "4 left to put without restriction to *all three boxes*"